# What is the best way to generate random ships in an array in Python?

Tags: python, arrays

Recently, I've been working on a battleship game for my CS2 class. The focus of this project is to create a board game using arrays, and I decided to create a battleship. I have most of the code, but I cannot figure out how to get ships to get randomly generated on a 10x10 array without the ships being...

A. The wrong length
B. Looping around the array

Below is the function I currently have.

```
def createShips(board):
    shipLen = [5,4,3,3,2]
    shipAvalible = 5
    directionposibilities = ["vertical", "horizontal"]
    j = 0
   

    
    for i in range(shipAvalible):
        boatMade = False

        #REGULAR VAR STATMENTS
        direction = random.choice(directionposibilities)   
        col = randint(0,9)
        row = randint(0,9) 

        

        while boatMade == False:
            
   
            if direction == "vertical":
                buildCount = 0
                if col + int(shipLen[i]) <= 11: 
                    colission = False
                    for i in range(0, int(shipLen[i])):
                        buildCount += 1
                        if board[int(row-i)][int(col)-1] == "X": 
                            if colission:
                                pass
                            else:
                                colission = True
                    if colission:
                        col = randint(0,9)
                        row = randint(0,9)
                    else:
                       
                        for j in range(buildCount):
                            board[int(row-j)][int(col)-1] = "X"
                            
                        boatMade = True
                else:
                    col = randint(0,9)
                    row = randint(0,9)
            if direction == "horizontal":
                if col + int(shipLen[i]) <= 10: 
                    colission = False
                    buildCount = 0
                    for i in range(0, int(shipLen[i])):
                        buildCount += 1
                        if board[int(row)][int(col)+i-1] == "X":
                            if colission:
                                pass
                            else:
                                colission = True
                    if colission:
                        col = randint(0,9)
                        row = randint(0,9)
                    else:
                       
                        for j in range(buildCount):
                            board[int(row)][int(col)+j-1] = "X"
                        boatMade = True
                else:
                    col = randint(0,9)
                    row = randint(0,9)
        shipAvalible = shipAvalible - 1
    
    return(board)

board = [["■"] * 10 for x in range(10)]

print(createShips(board))
```

If you have any idea why this may not work please let me know!

P.S. I am using another function that prints the array nicely, if you would like that for convenience, it is seen below:

```
def showBoard(board):
    print("   A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J")
    print("  ------------------------------")

    rownumb = 1
    for r in board:
        if rownumb == 10:
            space = ""
        else:
            space = " "
        print("%d|%s|" % (rownumb, space + "|".join(r)))
        rownumb += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok lets go over this:

1. length check

   `if col + int(shipLen[i]) <= 9:`  since arrays start at 0 in python the maximum index for a 10x10 board is 9, therefore you need to chek against 9 instead of 11
2. loop variables

   `for k in range(0, int(shipLen[i])):` using the same variable name for the outer and inner loop (while working in this specific case) is really bad form
3. collision check

   `if board[row+k][col] == "X":` you want to build the ships "forwards" so you use `row+k`, you can also forego int conversions when you only use integers to begin with
4. collsion check 2

   `if colission: pass   else: colission = True` This whole block can be shortened to `collision = True   break` since you dont need to keep checking for multiple collisions
5. buildcount

   `for j in range(buildCount):` unless you get a collision (then you wouldnt be in this branch) buildCount is always the same as `shipLen[i]` so it can be completly removed from your code
6. boat building

   `board[row+j][col] = "X":` same as before we build forwards
7. honorable mentions

   `shipAvailable = len(shipLen)` you could also remove this part completly and iterate over your ships directly in your out for loop

   Instead of radoomising your direction row and col on every break condition you could randomize it once at the start of your while loop

   `j = 0` unlike C you dont have to define your variables before using them in a loop, this statement does nothing

Comment: Thank you so much! I will take all these suggestions and incorporate them ASAP! I am sorry if some of your fixes are easy and common sense. I am relatively new to coding, and this really does help me!

Answer (score 0):

Edit: @Eumel was a bit faster and said it better [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70927674/18081746)

First of all, you have a inner and outer loop with the variable `i`, which might not actually interfere but it makes it harder to read the code. Consider renaming one of the variables.

When you create a `vertical` ship, you check the `col` rather than the `row` for index error, and does so against a value of 11 instead of your board size 10.

In the `vertical` case you build the ship "backwards" from the selected position, even though you checked that your board could fit the ship in the positive direction (And you place it in a column to the left). These negative values makes it such that your ships can wrap around.

In the `horizontal` case you are indexing a bit strange again where `board[int(row)][int(col)+i-1]` this gives that when `i=0` you place your ship an index further to the left than intended, again causing the ship to wrap when `col=0`.

Further more, you could remove a few redundant `if` statements and duplicate lines of code, by moving:

```
        direction = choice(directionposibilities)
        col = randint(0, 9)
        row = randint(0, 9)
```

Inside the `while` loop.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I know that there are some stupid mistakes and easy things that I should know, but you were a real help! I'm still relatively new to CS and this is a significant help to my learning of python. Have an amazing day!